# How can one write correct HTML to an inline Javascript inside a JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, jspx

Due to some reasons, I have to load two separate page header HTMLs in my page. One of them is a header for mobile view, and the other is for the desktop view. The rest of my page is responsive. My plan is to load both headers' HTMLs inside a JS that loads on page load and depending on page width populate the correct header's HTML inside my page, and hope the corresponding JS and CSS to load. I am doing this since the JS and CSS of the two header HTMLs are prone to clashing (and I can't tinker with these HTMLs), so I want only of them to load on a page load.

The problem is in writing HTML in JSP inside this inline JS. I repeatedly get errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

[image]

My code in JSP looks like this:

```
            <c:when test="${not empty hdrLoggedInHtml and not empty hdrLoggedInHtml_M}">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                            if($(window).width()>420)
                            {
                                $("#desktopHeader").html('<c:out value="${hdrLoggedInHtml}" escapeXml="false"/>');
                                $("#mobileHeader").html("");                                        
                            }else
                            {
                                $("#mobileHeader").html('<c:out value="${hdrLoggedInHtml_M}" escapeXml="false"/>');
                                $("#desktopHeader").html("");
                            }

                        });
                    });
                </script>

            </c:when>
```

I tried using fn:escapeXml but that didn't work either. It seems to me that the new line after `<html>` inside the string is not getting output properly or some invisible character is coming somehow. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put *hdrLoggedInHtml* into a html node which is display:none before it,like:

```
   <script>
         var global = {} ; global.url = '${url}';global.data = $.parseJSON('${data}');
   </script>
```

and then,put the  *script* at the bottom of the JSP page ,here is  one example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        if($(window).width()>420)
                        {
                            $("#desktopHeader").load(global.url,global.data);
                            $("#mobileHeader").html("");                                        
                        }else
                        {
                            $("#mobileHeader").html($('#'));
                            $("#desktopHeader").html("");
                        }

                    });
                });
```

Comment: The HTML inside hdrLoggedInHtml downloads JS and CSS of its own. If I put that in a div, then those resources will load, and I don't want that.

Comment: I'm changing it,putting it into script tag

Comment: I am getting the same error after trying your approach.

Comment: I guess the reason why it's like this is *${hdrLoggedInHtml}* itself has *newline* . When JSP template renders it,the line feed would be rendered along.So,I dont' think it's a good solution to make Response design.Howerver,use *<include>* jstl tag may effect.

Comment: Yes, I think that newline is the reason. But hdrLoggedInHtml is not static content. It is modified and passed to JSP by controller. So I can't put it into a static file and include it.

Comment: using function `$.load` to load a JSP via `AJAX` may help you.

Comment: Are you suggesting another server call just to fetch header? I don't think that would be a good idea. Plus maintaining session will also be a challenge.